# Get the text inside a button

Tags: android

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="blah blah">
```

How do I get the text inside `android:text`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
String buttontext = btn.getText().toString();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

you get text by.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
String yourText = (String)button.getText();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView button1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
String text = button1.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Button tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
String buttonName = tv.getText().toString();
```

**Edit according to the comment below, thanks :).**

Comment: tv.getText().toString(); required

Answer (score 2):

```
Button mButton;
mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
String buttontext=  mButton.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep all your strings in the strings.xml (rather than hard-coding them everywhere)

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="@string/button1_label">
```

In the strings.xml:

```
<string name="button1_label">blah blah</string>
```

Then you can easily get the text using:

```
Context.getString(R.string.button1_label)
```

You can find out more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).